# Exclude page self by appcache

Tags: html, browser-cache

I have an appcache (with NETWORK *). So now I visit my page with `<html manifest="/cache.appcache">`. Then the page itself is cached as all the images are. But I want the page self to not be cached. How can I do this? I thought `NETWORK *` would do the trick.

Regards,
Kevin

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML5 cache manifest no cache for html file itself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5045782/html5-cache-manifest-no-cache-for-html-file-itself)

Answer (score 1):

The appcache manifest always caches the master page.
If you are using Chrome check the cached files for your page here: chrome://appcache-internals

A workaround could be to put a hidden iframe somewhere on your page, which contains the appcache file to cache offline content. (take a look at "Preventing the application cache from storing masters with an iframe" here: http://labs.ft.com/2012/11/using-an-iframe-to-stop-app-cache-storing-masters/ )

A better solution could be to write your page to fetch new content from your server when it is opened - if the server cannot be reached, it can serve the last known content from the HTML5 local storage.

Comment: Could someone elaborate on why this is downvoted? I think it's a good answer, so I might have something to learn

Comment: Using application cache in an iframe is not a good solution. Yes, you'll download the files and cache them, but the browser will always check the server before loading the pages. You'll get a 304 from the server, and it is rather fast, but with a master file and a cache manifest you'll not even ask the server for a response - it will all be an internal job. I haven't downvoted you, by the way. But I haven't upvoted you either. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the iframe work around, and find it ripe with errors. Most browsers cache the data for the iframe where the page cannot get it.

**Instead make the page's content load via AJAX**. Basically have a blank html page with the manifest and javascript which pulls and adds its content from the server. This way only the blank html is cached, and content is always updated from the server.

Converting a page to this method can be very difficult, but it works. Making sure the appropriate javascript gets run at the correct time, probably requires some detangling. Moving around server code which won't be called when pulling from cache to the new ajax method.

Note: no need to pull conditional content from the server if the condition is in the query string, different query strings make a separate cache