# HTML5 Cache Manifest: Only fallback, no caching

Tags: html, caching, manifest, cache-manifest

I created a webapp which should **always use the most current files** and don't cache anything. BUT when the client goes offline, it should present the "offline.html" which continuously tries to load the "index.php" every 30sec.

Here is the thing: my index.php gets also cached because it has the manifest tag. But this **messes up the functionality** of my webapp.

So I wanted to ask, **what are the best solutions to use the cache manifest only for providing a fallback, not for caching anything else?**

index.php

```
<html manifest="/cache.manifest">
```

cache.manifest

```
CACHE MANIFEST

FALLBACK:
/ /offline.html

NETWORK:
*
```

I've found **this solution** here https://stackoverflow.com/a/19974768/1311566 where the guy uses an **iframe** to load an html with the manifest tag in it so that the index.php doesn't get cached. But I wanted to know if there are any other, or maybe even better, solutions out there.

Many thanks in advance,
Stefan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution described at https://stackoverflow.com/a/19974768/1311566 is correct. It's the only way to prevent the HTML files from being cached and only fallback to `/offline.html` if requests fail.

I build offline-compatible apps based on applicationCache since 3+ years now, and trust me this is the only way. If you like to have a nice JS API for the iframe Hack (and much more), you can use a library I've build: https://github.com/gr2m/appcache-nanny

By the way this iframe hack has been invented by the Financial Times Labs team, they put together a great tutorial with lots of background information on it: http://labs.ft.com/category/tutorial/